# Error after successfully for LDAP authentication

Tags: java, ldap

I am using email and password for LDAP authentication.Right after a successful authentication，I have some error in response returned. I suspect  this is due to a misconfiguration. I have monkey patched the authenticate part and pasted here, thanks in advance!

```
private Authenticator  createAuthenticator() throws Exception{
    NoOpDnResolver dnResolver = new NoOpDnResolver();
    final ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig();
    connectionConfig.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
    connectionConfig.setResponseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(6));
    connectionConfig.setLdapUrl("some ldap server");

    connectionFactory.setConnectionConfig(connectionConfig);
    connectionFactory.getConnection().open();
    final PoolConfig poolConfig = new PoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMinPoolSize(1);
    poolConfig.setMaxPoolSize(5);
    poolConfig.setValidateOnCheckOut(false);
    poolConfig.setValidateOnCheckIn(false);
    poolConfig.setValidatePeriodically(false);

    final BlockingConnectionPool connectionPool = new BlockingConnectionPool();
    connectionPool.setPoolConfig(poolConfig);
    connectionPool.setBlockWaitTime(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    connectionPool.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    connectionPool.initialize();
    final PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
    pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionPool(connectionPool);
    final PooledBindAuthenticationHandler handler = new PooledBindAuthenticationHandler();
    handler.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactory);
    final Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
    authenticator.setDnResolver(dnResolver);
    authenticator.setAuthenticationHandler(handler);
    return authenticator;
}


public void testLdap() throws Exception {
        connectionFactory = new DefaultConnectionFactory();
        final AuthenticationRequest request = new AuthenticationRequest("someemail", new org.ldaptive.Credential("somepassword"),
                ReturnAttributes.NONE.value());
        final AuthenticationResponse response = createAuthenticator().authenticate(request);
}
```

---

And here is related error logs:

> [2017-09-15 15:23:40.964] log4j - 9028 DEBUG [main] --- BindOperation:
>   execute request=[org.ldaptive.BindRequest@743893925::bindDn=someemail,
>   saslConfig=null, controls=null, referralHandler=null,
>   intermediateResponseHandlers=null] with
>   connection=[org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory$DefaultConnection@436338687::config=[org.ldaptive.ConnectionConfig@938941445::ldapUrl=someldapurl,
>   connectTimeout=PT3S, responseTimeout=PT6S, sslConfig=null,
>   useSSL=false, useStartTLS=false, connectionInitializer=null,
>   connectionStrategy=org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionStrategy@5bd3ca3c],
>   providerConnectionFactory=[org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnectionFactory@1647441786::metadata=[ldapUrl=someldapurl,
>   count=1], environment={com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout=3000,
>   java.naming.ldap.version=3,
>   java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory,
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout=6000}, classLoader=null,
>   providerConfig=[org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiProviderConfig@688662124::operationExceptionResultCodes=[PROTOCOL_ERROR,
>   SERVER_DOWN], properties={},
>   controlProcessor=org.ldaptive.provider.ControlProcessor@75b363c3,
>   environment=null, tracePackets=null, removeDnUrls=true,
>   searchIgnoreResultCodes=[TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, SIZE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED,
>   PARTIAL_RESULTS], classLoader=null, sslSocketFactory=null,
>   hostnameVerifier=null]],
>   providerConnection=org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnection@6ea3a513]

Comment: I think error related to fail to find role for authenticated user, not sure..

Comment: What part of `SERVER_DOWN` didn't you understand?

Comment: @EJP thanks for responding, as I said, instead of server problem, I suspect this is more likely a configuration issue, cause I do get the successful response for authentication. I am pretty fresh to ldap, could you point out some aspects that I need to check?